How can I find the side length of an equilateral triangle when the altitude is given?
This is probably a simple enough question, but I've only recently started my geometry class and am not familiar with the formulas.
The altitude of an equilateral triangle is given, 18 inches. Find the length of a side.
I think the side length formula is s = √(4A/√3). However, I don't know how to find the area without already having a side length.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The altitude is given by $\frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2}$, where $s$ is the side length.

Thanks, @sudeep5221. Could I rearrange that for s=2h/√3 where h is altitude and s is side length, since I need to solve for a side? Or rather, is that rearranged correctly?

Yes, your expression is correct, $s = \frac{2h}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Notice the altitude of an equilateral triangle is also the median. Hence, if we let $L$ represents the length of its sides and $H$ represents the length of its altitudes, then the Pythagorean theorem implies that:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^{2} + H^{2} = L^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{L^{2}}{4} + H^{2} = L^{2}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{3L^{2}}{4} = H^{2} \Longleftrightarrow L = \frac{2H}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}
Given that $H = 18\text{in}$, the desired result is easy to obtain.
